# Halmos Finite-Dimensional Vector Spaces: Ordered pairs of complex numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra

Paul R. Halmos "Finite-Dimensional Vector Spaces", 2e, chapter I, section 1, exercise 7.c:

> What happens (in both the preceding cases) if we consider ordered
>   pairs of complex numbers instead?

Question asked is if

- the set of ordered pairs $(a, b) \in \mathbb{C}^2$
- addition $(a_1, b_1) + (a_2, b_2) = (a_1 + a_2, b_1 + b_2)$
- multiplication $(a_1, b_1) \cdot (a_2, b_2) = (a_1a_2 - b_1b_2, a_1b_2 + a_2b_1)$

form a field.

I decided to check if the above given object has all the properties a field needs.

Currently, I'm stuck at the question if a multiplicative inverse exists for every $(a, b)$. This would require that

$$
(a, b)^{-1}(a,b) = (1, 0),
$$

since I found $(1, 0)$ to be the neutral element of multiplication.

I ended up with the following set of linear equations:

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
\alpha_1 & -\alpha_2 & -\beta_1 & \beta_2 \\
\alpha_2 & \alpha_1 & -\beta_2 & -\beta_1 \\
\beta_1 & -\beta_2 & \alpha_1 & -\alpha_2 \\
\beta_1 & \beta_2 & \alpha_1 & \alpha_2
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
\gamma_1 \\
\gamma_2 \\
\delta_1 \\
\delta_2
\end{array}
\right)
=
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
1 \\
0 \\
0 \\
0
\end{array}
\right),
$$

where $(a, b) = (\alpha_1 + i \beta_1, \alpha_2 + i \beta_2)$, and $(a, b)^{-1} = (\gamma_1 + i \delta_1, \gamma_2 + i \delta_2)$.

Applying LAPLACE's formula, I found the expression for the determinant of the matrix to be

$$
2(\alpha_1^2 + \alpha_2^2 + \beta_1^2 + \beta_2^2)(\alpha_1\alpha_2 + \beta_1\beta_2).
$$

Then, if $\alpha_1\alpha_2 + \beta_1\beta_2 = 0$, the determinant is $0$ and the solution to the system of equations is not unique.

May I conclude that there are cases when no (unique) inverse exists, and the above given object is not a field?

Comment: Try $(1,i)\cdot(1,-i)$.

Comment: Thank you @LordSharktheUnknown! This states that there are complex pairs s.t. $a \cdot b = 0$. But what does that imply?

Comment: In a field, if $a,b\neq0$, then $ab\neq0$.

Comment: Thank you @JoséCarlosSantos! My approach to get to the point stating that the mathematical object is not a field was rather mechanical. Is there an easier way?

Comment: An easier way than the one suggested by Lord Shark the Unknown? I don't think so.

Comment: Last time I checked there were infinitely many complex numbers, so the tag finite fields was inappropriate.

Comment: Recounted them: Jyrki's right! Sorry.